# onchange not working on IE but firing perfectly on Chrome and FF

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, cross-browser, onchange

I have a problem with an `onchange` event. It works just fine on Chrome and FF but not on IE. Here's the code:

```
<div class="panel-body panel-default upload">
    <div class="form-group upload">
        {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'scriptUpload/upload','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true, 'class' => 'fluid ui action labeled input')) !!}
        <label for="project" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Elementary script</label>

            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls input">
                    <input id="files" type="text" class="input upload" readonly>
                        <label class="col-sm-5">
                            <span class="btn btn-primary upload">
                                Browse&hellip; <input name='elementaryScript[]' id='elementaryScriptId' type="file" style="display: none;" multiple onchange="isUploadPossible(this)">
                            </span>
                        </label>

                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="success">
            {!! Form::button('Upload', array('id' => 'submitButton', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary upload', 'onClick' => 'fileExists()', 'disabled'=>'true')) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

And here is the JS function that's called:

```
function isUploadPossible(elem) {
    if (elem.value == "")
        elem.getRootNode().getElementsByTagName('button').submitButton.disabled = true;
    else
        elem.getRootNode().getElementsByTagName('button').submitButton.disabled = false;

}
```

So basically, when the user selects files, it should make the `disabled` attribute of the upload button to `false`.

I read here and there that it should be changed to `onclick` but I can't, since it has to be fired after the user has selected the files to be uploaded and `onclick` would be fired before.

EDIT: I actually happen to have this error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'getRootNode'
```

Comment: What error it is showing ?

Comment: There's no error, the button just stays disbaled. And when I use the debugger to check what's (not) happening I can see that the JS function is never called.

Comment: I actually have this error in the Console: `Object doesn't support property or method 'getRootNode'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it appears that `getRootNode` is just [supported by Chrome and Opera](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/getRootNode) so far.

Found a (very) dirty way to do but that works on IE, Chrome and FF:

```
elem.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('button').submitButton;
```